# What is the policy of who can delete comments?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, deleted-comments

What is the policy of who can delete comments?

And how does it guard against one or two persons being able to delete comments (or each other's comments) that otherwise may not be favorable to him or her?  Are there any guidelines for this?

Comment: Main Meta Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: Some comments can be deleted with a single flag. I only know one phrase that allows this, but it's not offensive. It's just highly overused by many users.

Comment: I wish no one could delete comments unless they're spam/abusive. Having been on SE sites for some years now, I find that most moderator behaviour on stack exchange is a net subtraction from the quality of the site when it comes to comment moderation.

Answer (score 16):

Only three types of people and one bot can delete comments:

1. The comment author.
2. [♦ Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)
3. Stack Overflow staff, who have moderator powers, including developers, who have all sorts of fun superpowers.
4. [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), an [automated user that deletes some really offensive or inappropriate comments from time to time, among many other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/238426). This is done in some cases as the result of flags (see below).

**The most any other user can do is flag a comment for moderator attention.*** As pointed out in the comments, that will *result* in a comment deletion in several scenarios: (1) the comment contains offensive or abused terms that trigger automatic cleanup by Community as the result of a single flag, (2) a moderator validates the flag, or (3) a total of three users flag the comment.

**The situation you are worried about—duels in the comments, with people deleting each other's remarks—basically can't happen.**

* Of course, various people (the above groups, as well as users with [certain privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)) can also delete a post (a question or answer), which takes comments on that post with it. But users with 10k rep can still see the deleted post with any comments that were not separately deleted. Only moderators and staff can see comments that were explicitly deleted.

Comment: for (2), can't 2 moderators go into a fight and delete each other's comments then?

Comment: I don't see in the http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges about deleting a comment. There is one for "20,000 Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges" but I have more than 20,000 and I don't see that I have the ability to delete any comment

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Technically, yes. If that ever happens, though, we have a very big problem with the community. And there are only 19 of us, out of [more than 5 million registered users](http://stackoverflow.com/company/about). So, sure, that's possible, but not something to lose any sleep over.

Comment: I would not want that power. What's the point of deleting a comment when you can have fun making it look silly instead?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I didn't say the privileges let you delete comments. They let certain users vote to delete *posts* (questions and answers). When a post is deleted, its comments disappear with it, although users with 10k rep can still see the deleted post with any comments that were not separately deleted.

Comment: Beyond the insta-deletion by the system for any comment that contains a select grouping of Carlin's famous words (and a few more), I believe a comment is also automatically deleted by the system upon receiving six comment flags by the community. That very rarely happens on SO, since moderators act on these well before that point, but it is possible.

Comment: … (The mod review could theoretically be skipped (except for each user's first n flags and later occasional random meta reviews) when ≥a flaggers have ≥b rep each and optionally all flaggers together ≥c rep;  but since the 6 flags case happens so rarely if ever, it's probably not worth implementing.)

Comment: @accolade I think you're worrying about a problem that doesn't really exist. It's a lot of work to create 6 sockpuppets and give them all enough reputation (>=15) to flag comments. That's very likely to be detected and get the person doing it suspended. And fraudulent/coordinated abuse of comment flags is just not a problem that comes up in the real world. I've never seen anyone complain on here or on MSE about this being an issue.

Comment: @EdCottrell, glad to hear that. :)  Thanks for the info!  **(** >`I think you're worrying about a problem that doesn't really exist.`< ↦ Well, at least I also worried about worrying about a problem that doesn't really exist (>`Sorry, I'm probably trying to solve problems here that don't exist.^^`<) – so at the end of the day I arguably also worried about a problem that did really exist ( – the problem of me worrying about a problem that doesn't really exist). __)__

Comment: [ The following comment is a repost of my first comment on this answer, edited to remove the superseded ping to BradLarson. ]

Comment: ([ Sorry, I'm probably trying to solve problems here that don't exist.^^ Feel free to ignore this in that case. :) ] That 6 flags system sounds like it could be easily abused through sock puppets. Therefore maybe the 6-flagged comments should only be hidden and remain in the mod queue (with low priority) until mod-reviewed. Actually, along with such a hidden-queue, it might make sense to hide comments already after 2 or 1 flags of users of sufficient rep or trustworthy flagging record, at least for the flagging reasons spam and offensiveness. (@EdCottrell))

Comment: @EdCottrell, feel free to purge our exchange if it seems more cluttery than useful for future readers! :)

Comment: "including developers, who have all sorts of fun superpowers." ... man, now I do want to know about those fun superpowers ^^