# Proper flag for when a comment almost directly restates another comment

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags

Recently I came across an answer with several comments stating ""Can only create methods" is pretty misleading." While reading them, I noticed one that had been made 1 year after the answer was posted. It read "[Can only create methods is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference#comment55407617_10839155)". Since it was repetitive, and reviving a 1 year old comment thread, I thought I should flag it, although after looking, I was unable to find a applicable flag reason. What would the proper flag, if any, should be used in this situation?

Comment: Just flag it "too chatty".

Comment: Or even "obsolete"

Comment: @torazabury Stack overflow is supported by the community, and it's upkeep depends on its users. I would like to ensure I'm using the proper flags, so as to make the job easier for moderators. And in short, no. I have nothing better to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the comment. If it fits one existing flag reason well, use that reason.

My advice for comments that don't appear at face value to be worthy of deletion is to use the custom flag. It's not like it really matters, the flags are [usually handled by mods in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322089).

It is also helpful (or harmless at worst) to provide a link to the duplicate comment.

From what I hear, the interface for handling comment flags sucks, so I think the context is valuable. The other thing is that you can't expect the mod to be an expert in the subject matter, so clearer is better.

Comment: *It's not like it really matters, the flags are handled by mods in the first place.* Comment flags do not scale well, recommending this may very well lead to moderator overflow (and most probably them postponing comment flags *ad infinitum*). Maybe we should just let these comments be, as if they actually are duplicates then the commenters are just making fools of themselves. Publicly.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Are you criticizing my suggestion or the way the system works? I'm not convinced that this would lead to an "overflow" in any sense; if anything it will help mods handle things more quickly than if they have to go around and guess why you flagged the comment. I think it's important to flag comments, including this type, to keep the comments from ruling Q&A.

Comment: I'm criticizing part of your suggestion (and technically also part of the way the system works, since we can flag comments for reasons other than spam or offensive in the first place), but I do not *completely* disagree with you. I only believe that, say, dozens of comment flags per rigorous user per day cannot possibly scale with our current moderation system. Time may prove me wrong, but it just doesn't compute *right now*.